# Adding user to MySql using iOS

Tags: php, ios

I am using the code below to add user to MySql, but record not added. Have a look to my Table on my server:

[image]

And her is my PHP file:

```
<?php
header( 'Content-type: text/xml');
mysql_connect( 'localhost', '********', '********');
mysql_select_db('*********');

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO user VALUES ( null, '".
    mysql_real_escape_string( $REQUEST['user']).
    "', '".
    mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['email']).
    "','".
    mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['contact']).
    "','".
    mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['description']).
    "','".);
    $data = array();
    $data['result'] = mysql_insert_id();
    header('userid: '.$data['result']);
    return json_encode($data);


?>

<success> />
```

And her is my Xcode:

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    //    if ([defaults stringForKey:@"user_preference"]) {
    [defaults setValue:[usernameTextFieldObj text] forKey:@"user_preference"];
    //    }
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                     @"http://MyWebSite/Folder/chat/adduser.php"];

    NSLog(@"url %@", url);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                                    init] ;
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user=%@&contact=%@&description=%@&email=%@",
                       usernameTextFieldObj.text,
                       contactNumberTextFieldObj.text,descriptionTextViewObj.text,emailidTextFieldObj.text] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [receivedData setLength:0];
    NSDictionary *responseHeaders = ((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response).allHeaderFields;

    NSLog(@"headers: %@", responseHeaders.description);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:[responseHeaders valueForKey:@"userid"] forKey:@"UserId"];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    if (chatParser)
        chatParser = nil;


    chatParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:receivedData];
   // [chatParser setDelegate:self];
    [chatParser parse];

    //    [receivedData release];

}
```

I am not good enough to sort out this problem. I hope to find the problem with you guys.

Comment: You are having an error or something...did you check the apache logs...can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: headers: {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 20;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Thu, 06 Oct 2016 15:31:22 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.10.1";
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
}

Comment: that what i have from Xcode console

Comment: Question...are you able to reach to `http://MyWebSite/Folder/chat/adduser.php` from your phone's browser?

Comment: You're simply ASSUMING that all of your db code will never fail. You have absolutely ZERO error handling in there. Never EVER assume success when dealing with external resources. Always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: yes, but it shows nothing, even if i call the php file from my browser

Comment: the PHP file must return success but it does not